# Interpolate polynomial and evaluate its values based on set of points

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, fast-fourier-transform

I have $n$ polynomial values at points $[1,..,n]$. I don't know its degree, it can be anything from $0$ to $n-1$. I need to evaluate polynomial values at points $[n+1,..,n+m]$.

In my case this is practical programming problem, $n$ and $m$ and quite big. I think I have to use Fast Fourier Transform because of its speed. I am working in modulo prime ring, so it's Number Theoretical Transform, but I think it doesn't change anything, since they have the same properties.

Comment: You need to know something about the degree. In general, for degrees $< n -1$, all you can do is a best-fit approximate solution. For degree $n-1$, there will be always be a unique solution, but that solution is likely to swing wildly between the support points, and will grow quickly outside them. For higher degrees you can choose additional conditions to smooth out the oscillations. Without knowing more about the problem, I can't say which you need.

Comment: I can find degree by calculating differences: $d_1(x)=f(x+1)-f(x),..., d_i(x)=d_{i-1}(x+1)-d_{i-1}(x)$, once all $d_k$ are const, degree is $k$. But this algorithm works in $O(n^2)$, and it is too slow for my case. I understand high degree polynomials swings crazy, but in my case all values are modulo prime.

Comment: The difference scheme will find the minimal degree polynomial that passes through every point. It is not "high degree" polynomials that swing wildly. It is this *minimal* degree polynomial that will do  Higher degree polynomials also have the freedom necessary to pass through all the points, but also have additional freedom to change direction and pass through them more efficiently. The minimal polynomial has no choice but to take them at steep angles, then swing around to pass through the next. Your modulo field just means it has the choice of going all the way around the field instead.

Comment: If you want a shortest path between the points, then you need at least $n-1$ degree to pass through the points, and an additional $n-1$ degrees to allow inflection points between them, for $2n-2$ degrees total. This will give you the major gains. Higher degrees will give only small improvements in path length. But that assumes shortest path is even useful to you, which I don't know. Maybe the minimal polynomial is fine. In any case, I can't advise you on techniques. i was just pointing that you need to consider what degree polynomial you are after.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for help. I was assuming if I just find $n-1$ degree polynomial, but actual minimal degree is smaller, my coefficients will be zero for high degrees. From this fact I assumed I should not worry about minimal degree polynomial and start with maximum possible degree. It turned out this is not the case. Task description actually says polynomial should be minimum possible degree.